# Loop over multiple JSON arrays to filter the relevant JSON object based on a key value in Ansible

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2

I am trying to loop over 2 different JSON array and filter only if the 2 key values are same.

I am comparing **cidr** from po-orig.json/po file and **subnet** from pocooling json. If the key values are same in both file, then print the pertaining details of pocooling json file as a list.

```
- name: Combine GP MGMT
      vars:
       pocidr: >-
         {{
          po 
          | json_query('ansible_facts.policyobject[].json[]')
         }}
       poname: >-
         {{
         pocidr
          | selectattr('cidr', '==', item.subnet)
          | map(attribute='name')
          | list
         }}
      set_fact:
       result: >-
         {{ 
            result | default([])
            +
            [poname]
         }}
      with_items: "{{ pocooling }}"
```

**Updated code**

```
 - name: Compare the Current & Actual GP policy
      set_fact: 
           pocidr: "{{ po | json_query(\"ansible_facts.policyobject[].json[]\") }}"

    - name: Combine GP MGMT
      vars:
       poname: 
         "{{
         pocidr
          | selectattr('cidr', '==', item.subnet)
          | map(attribute='name')
          | first
         }}"
      set_fact:
       result: 
         "{{ 
            result | default([])
            +
            [poname]
         }}"
      with_items: "{{ pocooling }}"
```

**pocooling.json**

```
[
    {
        "applianceIp": "10.10.10.10",
        "dhcpBootOptionsEnabled": false,
        "dhcpHandling": "Run a DHCP server",
        "dhcpLeaseTime": "1 day",
        "dhcpOptions": [],
        "dnsNameservers": "upstream_dns",
        "fixedIpAssignments": {},
        "id": 2222,
        "name": "Cooling",
        "networkId": "78984654989",
        "reservedIpRanges": [],
        "subnet": "10.10.10.0/28"
    },
    {
        "applianceIp": "10.10.10.10",
        "dhcpBootOptionsEnabled": false,
        "dhcpHandling": "Run a DHCP server",
        "dhcpLeaseTime": "1 day",
        "dhcpOptions": [],
        "dnsNameservers": "upstream_dns",
        "fixedIpAssignments": {},
        "id": 2222,
        "name": "Cooling",
        "networkId": "123456789",
        "reservedIpRanges": [],
        "subnet": "10.11.11.0/28"
    }
]
```

**po-orig.json(po)**

```
{
   "ansible_facts":{
      "policyobject":[
         {
            "invocation":{
               "module_args":{
                  "status_code":[
                     200,
                     201,
                     202
                  ],
                  "validate_certs":false
               }
            },
            "item":{
               "id":"123456",
               "name":"DC"
            },
            "json":[
               {
                  "category":"network",
                  "cidr":"10.1.1.1/28",
                  "createdAt":"2021-11-23T19:48:21Z",
                  "groupIds":[
                     
                  ],
                  "id":"545649843651365",
                  "name":"JM-Privat",
                  "networkIds":[
                     "545649843651365"
                  ],
                  "type":"cidr",
                  "updatedAt":"2021-11-23T19:48:21Z"
               },
               {
                  "category":"network",
                  "cidr":"10.10.10.0/28",
                  "createdAt":"2021-12-07T13:54:05Z",
                  "groupIds":[
                     "897987654689854"
                  ],
                  "id":"564678984565465",
                  "name":"PO-L-DE-MCC-COOLING_DMZ_LAB",
                  "networkIds":[
                     
                  ],
                  "type":"cidr",
                  "updatedAt":"2021-12-07T13:54:05Z"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**Error:**

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: {{ pocidr\n | selectattr('cidr', '==', item.subnet)\n | map(attribute='name')\n | list\n}}: 'dict object' has no attribute 'cidr
```

**Expected result**

```yaml
[
    {
        "applianceIp": "10.10.10.10",
        "dhcpBootOptionsEnabled": false,
        "dhcpHandling": "Run a DHCP server",
        "dhcpLeaseTime": "1 day",
        "dhcpOptions": [],
        "dnsNameservers": "upstream_dns",
        "fixedIpAssignments": {},
        "id": 2222,
        "name": "Cooling",
        "networkId": "78984654989",
        "reservedIpRanges": [],
        "subnet": "10.10.10.0/28"
    }
]
```

**Complete Playbook**

```
- name:  Test 
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    pocooling: "{{ lookup('file', 'pocooling.json') | from_json }}"

  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: po-orig.json
        name: po
    - name: Combine GP MGMT
      vars:
        poname: "{{ po|json_query('ansible_facts.policyobject[].json[]')|
                    selectattr('cidr', '==', item.subnet)|
                    map(attribute='name')|
                    list }}"
      set_fact:
        result: "{{ result|default([]) + [poname] }}"
      loop: "{{ pocooling }}"
```

Comment: [edit] the question and make it [mre] with the focus on **minimal**. Live data is not necessary to solve your problem. Minimize it and add the expected result.

Comment: @Vladimir Botka, Thanks for your comment, i have added the expected output. The sample JSON's are added with only minimal details without adding much data, but retaining the structure as is.

Comment: Thank you. It's better. You might want to minimize it further. See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the list

```yaml
  pocooling:
  - networkId: '78984654989'
    subnet: 10.10.10.0/28
  - networkId: '123456789'
    subnet: 10.11.11.0/28
```

Select list of *cidr*

```yaml
  _cidr: "{{ ansible_facts.policyobject|json_query('[].json[].cidr') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  _cidr:
  - 10.1.1.1/28
  - 10.10.10.0/28
```

Then [select](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) the items that fit the condition

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ pocooling|selectattr('subnet', 'in' , _cidr) }}"
      vars:
        _cidr: "{{ ansible_facts.policyobject|json_query('[].json[].cidr') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - networkId: '78984654989'
    subnet: 10.10.10.0/28
```

---

Your code, fixed and simplified

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: po-orig.json
        name: po
    - name: Combine GP MGMT
      vars:
        poname: "{{ po|json_query('ansible_facts.policyobject[].json[]')|
                    selectattr('cidr', '==', item.subnet)|
                    map(attribute='name')|
                    list }}"
      set_fact:
        result: "{{ result|default([]) + [poname] }}"
      loop: "{{ pocooling }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  result:
  - - PO-L-DE-MCC-COOLING_DMZ_LAB
  - []
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, the solution is working for me. But just wanted to know what was the mistake in my code where i was getting an error . Could you please let me know the mistake in my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I have done as you suggested(please find the updated code) and still i am getting the same error as before.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. But unfortunately the updated code is not working for me. I am still getting the same error as `'dict object has no attribute cidr'`. I didn't do any kind of modifications, i just copy pasted your updated code and that is throwing the same error.

Comment: I've fixed your code.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort for providing the solution. But unfortunately i am always getting the same error whatever the changes you are suggesting. Please find my Complete Playbook, it contains only the code you have suggested and it throws the same error.

Comment: The code you posted [works as expected](https://gist.github.com/vbotka/7033003b802be4bb19ed4a623a4fc47f).

Comment: Oh that's really confusing. Now i doubt about the environment issue, do you have any suggestion about what could be causing this issue?